# How can I add header metadata without adding the <h1>?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I'm writing something in markdown and converting it to html with pandoc, but when I add the `title` variable in the yaml header, it also adds an `<h1>` to the top of the document, which I don't want. In the pandoc documentation it says to use the `title-meta` variable, but it still says

```
[WARNING] This document format requires a nonempty <title> element.
```

Is there a way to set the title without adding the title block?

command I'm using:

```
pandoc -s "file.md" -o "file.html"`
```

output of `pandoc --version`:

```
pandoc 2.10.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.21, texmath 0.12.0.2, skylighting 0.8.5
Default user data directory: C:\Users\noah\AppData\Roaming\pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2020 John MacFarlane
Web:  https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness
for a particular purpose.
```

Comment: Weird, right? Converting from Markdown, I almost always have a top-level `# Headline`, so adding an extraneous `<h1>` is not something I would want Pandoc to do for me. Maybe there are some formats where that makes more sense…

Answer (score 6):

One can set an explicit title with `--metadata=title="My title"` while simultaneously preventing the output of the `<h1>` and `<header>` elements by setting the template variable `title` to an empty string:

```
pandoc --metadata=title="Fancy title" --variable=title="" ...
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!